# Jquery - If statement for multiple input box scenarios

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong with my form validation below?

Basically if the names variable doesn't contain anything I want the input box to display 'please enter your name', but if they resubmit and still haven't added a name I need the if statement to pick up the phrase and still not validate.

Its driving me nuts - any help gratefully received!

Cheers
Paul

```
 if((names.length == 0) || (names != 'Please Enter Your Name')){  
        var error = true;  
        $('.error').fadeIn(500);  
        $('.nStar').fadeIn(500);
        $('#name').val('Please Enter Your Name');

    }else{  
        setTimeout("errorOut()",1000);
        $('.nStar').fadeOut(500);

    }
```

Comment: If you're doing this onsubmit, then you should return false if validation fails. Seeing the rest of your code would be helpful.

Comment: what exactly is not working about your code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement is checking if the value of the input is not `Please Enter Your Name`. I believe you want to check if it is.

This line:

```
if((names.length == 0) || (names != 'Please Enter Your Name')){
```

Should change to:

```
if((names.length == 0) || (names == 'Please Enter Your Name')){
```

This is assuming that the `names` variable consists of the `input` element's value.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `!=` in the `if` condition with `==` becouse if `names != 'Please Enter Your Name'` then `names` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new attribute for this in html5, set the placeholder attribute to "please enter your name" and it will be visible in the input area and disappear when focused and wont be sent into any posts.

to answer your real question, change (names != 'Please Enter Your Name') to (names == 'Please Enter Your Name')  in the if-statement, you are asking "if the length of the name is zero, OR the name *isnt* 'please enter your name' then show error". you want to change that isnt to an is.